# how to pass accurate multiple selections data using ui-selectable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I am useing jquery-ui selectable, I choose multiple divs, **For example: divs 1-3 and divs 5-6** after the selection I pass the divs's info to an array and  later to a string (strToSend). the problem is : when I choose divs 1-3 and divs 5-6 I get this Information : 
for divs **1-3** : 100,200,300.
for divs **5-6** :100,200,300,400,500,600. -> what I really need is to get: 500,600.At first I thought that I need to clear my array in each loop so I tried : `_info1.length = 0;  _info1 = [];` - no change.
I hope my problem is clear, please ideas what to do ?..

//HTML

```
<div class="ui-selectable" id="day" style="width: 100px; float: left;">
 Sunday
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="1" >100 </div>
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="2" > 200 </div>
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="3" > 300 </div>
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="4" > 400 </div>
   <div class="ui-selectee" id="5"> 500 </div>    
<div class="ui-selectee" id="6"> 600 </div>    
<div class="ui-selectee" id="7"> 700 </div>    
</div>
```

//Jquery

```
 $(function () {    
        $("#day").bind("mousedown", function (event) {
            return event.metaKey = true;
        }).selectable({
            stop: function () {              
                _info1.push(0);              
                $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {                  
                    var id = this.id;
                    _info1.push(id);
                });                 
                strToSend += _info1[0] + "_" + _info1[1] + "-" + _info1[_info1.length - 1] + "*";                                                          

            }
        });});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tS2cV/

Not sure where you're declaring your _info1 but it looks like you just want it to hold the divs you've selected. Your each function (below) goes through and grabs all divs that have been selected, so you don't have to manually push anything into it beforehand.

All I did was declare _info inside of the stop function - I'm sure what you were doing with the string to send so I removed it for simplicity:

```
$(function () {    
    $("#day").bind("mousedown", function (event) {
        return event.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable({
        stop: function () {
            var _info1 = [];
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {                  
                var id = this.id;
                _info1.push(id);
            });                                                                       
alert(_info1);
        }
    });});
```

Comment: It is very close to the result I need! but the problem is that        _info1.push(0); happen once.I get now:0,100,200,300,500,600  and I need for example of an array :0,100,200,300,**0**,500,600 Any idea for that?

Comment: So you want to iterate through the _info1 array and build the string from that?

Comment: I dont iterate through the _info1 array for my string (**strToSend**) I take only the selections edges(100 and 300 for example) and the number zero (which separate between selections in my array).

Comment: You're selecting the divs by their class 'ui-selected', so you'll have to clear that class somehow between when they're selected.